# How to validate 3 form on click of one button Angular 6 TS

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services, validation, angular6

I'm getting data from 3 forms and saving into 3 other services/tables.

Now I want to validate 3 forms data, If the user does not fill any required field so it should show some error message.

Please give me any example of it.

Comment: Please post your code  in order to get helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check every form in a single method using `.valid` property of `Form` like below -

```
commonMethod() {
    if (this.form1.valid && this.form2.valid && this.form3.valid){
       console.log('All Valid Forms');
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for formGroup and formControl?

Comment: No, because `this.form1` is already of type `FormGroup`. You are using reactive forms right?